# Flutter handle scroll actions (PrimaryScrollController reverse listview)

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll, reverse, scrollcontroller

On iOS, tapping the status bar makes PrimaryScrollController go to the top:
https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/platform-adaptations#return-to-top

> On iOS, tapping the OS status bar scrolls the primary scroll controller to the top position. There is no equivalent behavior on Android.

My PrimaryScrollController is attached to a ListView with `reverse:true`, so tapping the status bar makes it scroll to the bottom.

Docs say PrimaryScrollView handles ScrollAction if not handled by another scroll controller.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PrimaryScrollController-class.html

> If a ScrollAction is not handled by an otherwise focused part of the application, the ScrollAction will be evaluated using the scroll view associated with a PrimaryScrollController

How can I handle scroll actions myself so I can reverse the direction PrimaryScrollController goes when the status bar is tapped?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is likely going to be reversing the items in your list instead of using the `reverse: true` flag of ListView.

For example:

```dart
ListView(
  children: [
    Container(),
    Container(),
  ].reversed.toList(),
),
```

Trying to solve this any other way would get pretty involved. Since we don't have access to the StatusBar we can't override its behavior or listen for taps on it.

Comment: That wont work for me. I need lazy loading at the top of the ListView and keeping it regular makes lazy loading happen at the bottom :(

Comment: @BradenBagby I probably won't be able to look at this more until Monday but I'll get back to you on this. I'm not as privy on the iOS side of things so if anyone else wants to chime in that'd be awesome.